# How to show property of json string using interpolation in Angular 6+?

Tags: angular, interpolation, ngfor

Let's say we have a list of JSON object like this one:

```
data = {
   id: 1,
   someObjAsString: '{"p1":"a", "p2": "b"}',
   ...
   ... other properties
}
```

Using *ngFor I want to display p2 from someObjAsString:

```
<div *ngFor="let data of dataList">
{{data.someObjAsString.p2}} <!-- What should I do here to display p2 property of someObjAsString-->
</div
```

**JSON.parse() is definitly not working**

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `someObjAsString` is object, then you can use [keyvalue](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) pipe:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of dataList.someObjAsString | keyvalue">
    Key: <b>{{item.key}}</b> and Value: <b>{{item.value}}</b>
</div>
```

Usually `ngFor` is used to iterate through arrays.

**UPDATE:**

As your object is stored as string, then we can use [json.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to construct the JavaScript value or object:

```
data = {
  id: 1,
  someObjAsString: '{"p1":"a", "p2": "b"}',
  anotherObj: '{"p1":"a", "p2": "b"}'
};


ngOnInit(){
    for (const key in this.data) {
        if (this.data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
             this.data[key] = JSON.parse(this.data[key]);
        }
     }
     console.log(this.data);
}
```

And HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data | keyvalue">
    Key: <b>{{item.key}}</b> and Value: <b>{{item.value | json}}</b>

    <div *ngFor="let someObj of item | keyvalue">
        someObj Key: <b>{{someObj.key}}</b> 
          and someObjValue: <b>{{someObj.value | json}}</b>
    </div>
</div>
```

[A complete workstackblitz example can be see here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ta4hvh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: but I need other properties of the item also, Which doesn't seem to be accessible inside loop using your solution